# How to achieve Screen broadcasting(Custom View) with other users in iOS?(Objective c/Swift)

Tags: ios, webrtc, remote-desktop, replaykit

Basically I need to broadcast custom view or screen with multiple user.
e.g. I'm performing some of actions on view like typing so that screen I will share with other users not internal. So they can see whatever happens on screen.

I have checked ReplayKit and WebRTC but not able get more idea.

Kindly please provide guidance how can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReplayKit to broadcast your screen to other people. check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35546807)